# Reference count for OVERLAPPED structure

Tags: c++, asynchronous, overlapped-io

I found an article i find quite interesting. There is just one thing i cannot wrap my head around. 
(http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/file-system-part-1-platform-specific-api-design/)
The author describes a File class which is able to handle synchronous and asynchronous file operations. For the asynchronous operation he uses a self-contained object which keeps track of the asynchronous operation internally.
The class looks like this:

```
class OsAsyncFileOperation
{
public:
  OsAsyncFileOperation(HANDLE file, size_t position);
  OsAsyncFileOperation(const OsAsyncFileOperation& other);
  OsAsyncFileOperation& operator=(const OsAsyncFileOperation& other);
  ~OsAsyncFileOperation(void);

  /// Returns whether or not the asynchronous operation has finished
  bool HasFinished(void) const;

  /// Waits until the asynchronous operation has finished. Returns the number of transferred bytes.
  size_t WaitUntilFinished(void) const;

  /// Cancels the asynchronous operation
  void Cancel(void);

private:
  HANDLE m_file;
  ReferenceCountedItem<OVERLAPPED>* m_overlapped;
};
```

And is used like this:

```
OsAsyncFileOperation ReadAsync(void* buffer, size_t length, size_t position);
```

Now i am wondering: What is the role of the `ReferenceCountedItem<OVERLAPPED>* m_overlapped;` variable? I know that this somehow counts the references, but i am not sure how it is used here, especially since the constructor is not getting passed the `OVERLAPPED` structure. How does this class now about the `OVERLAPPED` structure used in the `ReadAsync` or `WriteAsync` method?
I tried to implement the `ReferenceCountedItem` class, since it is not specified in the article:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class ReferenceCountedItem {

public:
    ReferenceCountedItem(T* data) :m_data(data), m_refCounter(1)
    {}

    ~ReferenceCountedItem() {}

    int addReference()
    {
        return ++this->m_refCounter;
    }

    int removeReference()
    {
        return --this->m_refCounter;
    }

private:
    T* m_data;
    int m_refCounter;
};
```

I am mostly unsure of how this all is sticking together. Maybe someone can explain a little bit more about it. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: We can't see the OsAsyncFileOperation constructor, no need to make us guess at what it looks like.

Comment: I think you could use `std::shared_ptr` to replace `ReferenceCountedItem` if you have it available in your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere the author is allocating the OVERLAPPED struct on the heap, with `new` or `GlobalAlloc`. Then, in the copy constructor and `operator=`, he is copying the pointer. Since there can be multiple objects using the pointer he is using reference counting to know when it's ok to delete the OVERLAPPED pointer.

Comment: I am not quite sure i understand what you mean. Wouldn't the OVERLAPPED struct be allocated inside the `ReadAsync` or `WriteAsync` (because the call to ReadFile and WriteFile with the OVERLAPPED struct would happen there)? How could the `OsAsyncFileOperation` now about the pointer then?

Comment: You would have to look at the implementation of `ReadAsync()` and `WriteAsync()` to answer that. We cannot see that here. Either they are using some internal trickery to get an `OVERLAPPED` pointer into a new `OsAsyncFileOperation`, or the article does not accurately reflect what the code is really doing.

Comment: Alright. That was what i was thinking, too. Was just not sure if i was missing something. Thank you.